# SQL get x previous records by using previous record column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL table that has some kind of events in it.
There are multiple columns in for the events, but the three columns that are of interest for us are: id, type, previous_event_id.

I am using PostgreSQL

What I would like to achieve is to get the 5 or 10 or x previous events for a specific event. How is this achievable via SQL?

PP: Is this the best approach to store previous_event column for each event? I have indexed the id, type and previous_event_id columns.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: You'll need a recursive CTE for this, there are many examples online.

Comment: Sorry I am using PostgreSQL. I needed to find a generic answer like look up recursive CTE which I will do noe. Or this is not the best way to do it performance wise, you should make a bridge table. I don't think any code is relevant in this question.

Comment: If `previous_event_id` builds up a hierarchy or chain  of  events, then yes a recursive CTE is the way to go. Code (e.g. `CREATE TABLE` statements) and example data (including the expected results) **are** relevant. Otherwise you might get answers that simply won't work for you

Comment: Look into window functions, it lets you access previous rows.